SwiftUI reverse order of views in @ViewBuilder using parameter packs
Trying to use parameter packs to avoid duplicating this function
@ViewBuilder
public func Group<C0, C1, C2, C3>(reversed: Bool, @ViewBuilder for content: () -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3)>) -> some View {
    let contentResult = content()
    if !reversed {
        contentResult
    } else {
        let (c0, c1, c2, c3) = contentResult.value
        TupleView((c3, c2, c1, c0))
    }
}

It reverses the order of child views. At call site looks like this:
HStack {
  Group(reversed: condition) {
     view1
     view2
     view3
  }
}

Not sure if parameter packs is the right solution for this.

What's your question? Are you trying to generalise your Group function to any number of input Views? You say you're trying to use parameter packs, but there's no parameter packs in your question.

I would use the new ForEach that lets you do this normally

@DavidPasztor Exactly. I didn’t post the code with parameter packs because it was pretty bad.

You can easily do this using Group(subviews:) in iOS 18+.
struct ReversedModifier: ViewModifier {
    let reversed: Bool
    @Namespace var ns
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group(subviews: content) { views in
            if reversed {
                ForEach(views.reversed()) {
                    $0.matchedGeometryEffect(id: $0.id, in: ns)
                }
            } else {
                ForEach(views) {
                    $0.matchedGeometryEffect(id: $0.id, in: ns)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Group where Content: View {
    func reversed(_ flag: Bool = true) -> some View {
        modifier(ReversedModifier(reversed: flag))
    }
}

Note that SwiftUI already has a Group, so I would avoid calling your own function Group as well. Instead, here I have added a reversed modifier to SwiftUI's Group. The matchedGeometryEffects aren't technically necessary, but I added them anyway so that the animation when reversed changes looks as if the views are actually reversing.
Usage:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var flag = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                Text("Foo")
                Text("Bar")
                Text("Baz")
                Text("Gaz")
            }
            .reversed(flag)
            Toggle("Reversed", isOn: $flag.animation())
        }
    }
}

For earlier versions, you can use the _VariadicView APIs.
struct ReversedModifier: ViewModifier {
    let reversed: Bool
    @Namespace var ns
    
    private struct MultiViewRoot<Content: View>: _VariadicView_MultiViewRoot {
        @ViewBuilder let views: (_VariadicView.Children) -> Content

        func body(children: _VariadicView.Children) -> some View {
            views(children)
        }
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        _VariadicView.Tree(
            MultiViewRoot { views in
                if reversed {
                    ForEach(views.reversed()) {
                        $0.matchedGeometryEffect(id: $0.id, in: ns)
                    }
                } else {
                    ForEach(views) {
                        $0.matchedGeometryEffect(id: $0.id, in: ns)
                    }
                }
            }
        ) { content }
    }
}


Parameter packs are not suitable for this, because you cannot reverse the order of the parameter packs - there is no "reverse expansion" of value packs. Hypothetically, if a syntax like that did exist, you could do something like:
func group<each T: View>(_ views: repeat each T) -> some View {
    // I made up the ".reversed" syntax 
    TupleView((repeat each views).reversed)
}

The usage would be not very SwiftUI-like,
group(
    View1(),
    View2(),
    View3()
)


Is _VariadicView a private API?

@LescaiIonel No. It's just undocumented. It's actually marked as @frozen, so it's even ABI-stable.

You can use environment's layoutDirection:
HStack {
   view1
   view2
   view3
}.environment(\.layoutDirection, condition ? .rightToLeft : .leftToRight)

